# Swift MoveItem fails due to file "does not exist"

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm trying to rename a folder within my app, but the moveItem method is behaving strangely. Here is my code:

```
try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("parentFolder").appendingPathComponent("folderIWantToMove"), to: FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("parentFolder").appendingPathComponent("newFolderName"))
```

This fails and the message in the debugger is:

```
“folderIWantToMove” couldn’t be moved to “parentFolder” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder containing the latter doesn’t exist.
```

But when I run this in the lldb:

```
print FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("parentFolder").appendingPathComponent("folderIWantToMove").path)
```

and

```
print FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("parentFolder").path)
```

both return true, meaning both folders do exist. I've read some other questions with similar problems and most of them say that it is because of sandboxing. If this is the case how could I be able to change the name of and erase files within the user's document directory?

Just in case, I'm using swift 5 and running everything on an iPad with iPadOS 13 from Xcode 12 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue there is that you are not renaming it, you are trying to move your directory from inside your documents directory to the application directory which is out of your bundle and unreachable from your app in iOS.

```
let document = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let parentFolder = document.appendingPathComponent("parentFolder")
let folderIWantToMove = parentFolder.appendingPathComponent("folderIWantToMove")
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderIWantToMove, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    print("folder and sub folder created")
    print("folderIWantToMove path:", folderIWantToMove.path)
    // renaming it
    let newFolderName = parentFolder.appendingPathComponent("newFolderName")
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: folderIWantToMove, to: newFolderName)
    print("folder renamed to:", newFolderName.path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if I get your answer completely. I don't think I'm trying to move my directory from inside my bundle (I don't think I even know how to access my bundle). The idea is that at a certain point the user creates a folder like you did, and if he wants to rename it he can do so later as well. I'm actually pretty much doing what you did here I think. I create the folders exactly the same and I was putting the names I gave as an example. So the part after //renaming it is basically the line of code I gave. Thank  you though! Maybe you're right but I am too dumb to see it haha.

Comment: Your destination needs to be at the same location. You are appending the directory name to the application directory instead of the parent folder at the documents directory

Comment: your error is here `to: FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("parentFolder").appendingPathComponent("newFolderName")`

Comment: just change `.applicationDirectory` to `.documentDirectory`

Comment: Alright I get it now. Thank you so much this worked! Sorry for the troubles! It was a typo hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same file problem, but on macOS. I fixed it by adding the "com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write" entitlement and setting it as true. I hope this helps! (Also, make sure to set the app sandbox entitlement to false)

Comment: question is tagged as iOS

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm looking a little more into this because I'd rather set the app sandbox entitlement to false as a last resource if nothing else can be done. Either way thank you a lot!

Comment: @WaynarBocangel there is no way to accomplish that in iOS. I mean sandbox it is not optional in iOS.